# Question on identification of a compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, carbohydrates, ozone

**Question:**
[image]
*Multiple correct answers are possible*

**My Approach:**

I just found structure Q for all options A, B, C and D for which I have uploaded the structures below with their corresponding options.

[image]

Of course, option B cannot be correct since the molecular formula of the compound Q doesn't match with the one obtained after the reductive ozonolysis.
What I know about Molisch test is it gives the violet ring when an alcoholic solution of 1-naphthol is added to the carbohydrate solution. But I don't know how to proceed after this step as I don't know how to identify which of the compounds react with Molisch reagent.

Comment: Generally Q is dehydrated with H2SO4 to form a furfuraldehyde before the Molisch test. In which case Q must be at least a C5 aldehyde. Try this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/106734/clarification-in-the-mechanism-for-molischs-test-for-glucose/106758#106758